# Updating application data from Firebase without opening the application

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Is it possible that an application's listview updates the data from Firebase without even opening the application?

I am working on a restaurant application which has to work offline, so the user must NOT open the application to get the new menu, rather it must be updated automatically (whenever the user is connected to internet) even if the application isn't opened. Is it possible to be achieved?

Answer (score 0):

I think you're confusing updating the DATA with updating the MENU. A menu is a rendered object - if you're driving it with a listview, naturally it won't be updated when the app isn't running because there's no reason to draw a listview update if the listview isn't being shown.

But you can absolutely update the data, and we do this in News Rush to give the user access to new data while offline, if they were online earlier. Just make sure persistence is enabled and run the same query that drives your listview. Make sure the path/params are identical. Persistence will remember that data and if the user is offline the new menu will still show correctly the next time the app is started.

Comment: do you mean by online that the app is running or the mobile is connected to internet?

Answer (score 0):

You should update it outstide the app, but, you can enable offline capabilities,

**Enabling Offline Capabilities on Android**

```
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().setPersistenceEnabled(true);
```

> Firebase apps work great offline and we have several features to make
>   the experience even better. Enabling disk persistence allows your app
>   to keep all of its state even after an app restart. We provide several
>   tools for monitoring presence and connectivity state.

To keep data fresh:

> **Keeping Data Fresh**
>
> The Firebase Realtime Database synchronizes and stores a local copy of
>   the data for active listeners. In addition, you can keep specific
>   locations in sync.

```
DatabaseReference scoresRef =
 FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("scores");
 scoresRef.keepSynced(true);
```

> The client will automatically download the
>   data at these locations and keep it in sync even if the reference has
>   no active listeners. You can turn synchronization back off with the
>   following line of code.
>
> `scoresRef.keepSynced(false);` By default, 10MB of previously synced
>   data will be cached. This should be enough for most applications. If
>   the cache outgrows its configured size, the Firebase Realtime Database
>   will purge data that has been used least recently. Data that is kept
>   in sync, will not be purged from the cache.

Read more:

[Enabling Offline Capabilities on Android](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/offline-capabilities)